# Angular 8 : Set default selected value for select tag

Tags: html, angular, html-select, ngfor

I want to set a default option value for select tag, the values are declared as table in my component and showed with ngFor directive :

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <span class="badge badge-theme mb-3">Quantité</span>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option *ngFor="let quantity of Quantities" [ngValue]="quantity">{{quantity}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <span class="badge badge-theme mb-3">Message personnalisé</span>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**components.ts**

```
  Quantities = Array(50).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);
```

Comment: your select is getting populated with values and you are unable to set default value, is that right?

Comment: yes that's it @PareshLomate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-naczpj).

What I did is created a variable in compoent and then bonded it with select tag. `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"`.

The variable then can be used as per your logic.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it the following way:

**component.html**

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="seletedValue" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option *ngFor="let quantity of Quantities" [ngValue]="quantity">{{quantity}}</option>
 </select>
```

**component.ts**

```
seletedValue = ''; // set some default value from Quantities
```

OR

```
component.html

 <select [(ngModel)]="seletedValue" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option value="" [disabled]="true">Select quantity</option>
        <option *ngFor="let quantity of Quantities" [ngValue]="quantity">{{quantity}}</option>
 </select>
```